# Any possible ways to make this query simpler or maybe better

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query which I execute against PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT ((SELECT max(p.units_in_stock) FROM products p WHERE p.id = 'apple') - sum(o.quantity))
FROM orders o 
WHERE o.product_id = 'apple';
```

I used `sum` in the first inner `SELECT` to get 'value'.

Just getting started with SQL, so maybe this query can be optimized or made shorter.

The purpose of this query is to calculate how many products can be ordered by given id. Basically, the formula is `product.units_in_stock - sum(order.quantity)`.

[image]

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually fine, although you could express this version more simply using:

```
SELECT (SELECT max(p.units_in_stock)
        FROM products p
        WHERE p.id = o.product_id
       ) - SUM(o.quantity)
FROM orders o
WHERE o.product_id = 'apple'
GROUP BY o.product_id;
```

I'm not sure why you would need aggregation on the `product` table -- it is not clear why there would be more than one row per product in such a table.

This would more colloquially be written as:

```
select max(p.units_in_stock) - sum(o.quantity)
from products p join
     orders o
     on o.product_id = p.id
where p.id = 'apple';
```

I should also note that the query itself doesn't really make sense.  I would expect that existing orders would already be subtracted from the `units_in_stock` . . . but your data model may be doing something else.

Comment: So you suggest changing `units_in_stock` as soon as new order is placed?

Comment: @SebastianLore . . . I don't know what your system is doing.  I'm just commenting on things that look awkward in the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than 1 rows for each product in the table `products`?

If the answer is *yes* then you need `SUM()` and not `MAX()`:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(p.units_in_stock) FROM products p WHERE p.id = o.product_id) - SUM(o.quantity)
FROM orders o 
WHERE o.product_id = 'apple';
```

If the answer is *no* then you don't need any aggregation in the table `products`:

```
SELECT (SELECT p.units_in_stock FROM products p WHERE p.id = o.product_id) - SUM(o.quantity)
FROM orders o 
WHERE o.product_id = 'apple';
```